# after curl post, how to check the postfield - to debug

Tags: php, debugging, post, curl

i have a curl post somehing like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$cpUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $varpost); // post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Return the output in string format
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch); // Execute
```

how can i check after curl_close ($ch); what post field variables were sent? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i check after curl_close ($ch); what post field variables were
>   sent?

Your script provides the variables sent with the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` options, so if the cURL executed successfully, you already have those variables:

```
...
$output = curl_exec($ch); // Execute

//show the POST fields if they were sent successfully
if($output) print_r($varpost);
else echo "cURL failed: no POST fields sent";
```

Comment: it displays empty when i display as .....$output = curl_exec ($ch); 
$rr= curl_getinfo($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS);
info("paramspassed:",$rr);
@beetleJuice

Comment: @Ps-kl I don't understand why you're saying this; I did not suggest you use `curl_getinfo`.  Besides you cannot use `curl_getinfo` with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` as the 2nd parameter. See the docs for what's allowed: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to examine what data is actually beeing transfered between the client and the server